# CSS click effect

Tags: css

[image]
[image]

I made this thing with javascript to increment/decrement an input field. It has a hover state but it lacks a click state.

Is there a neat way to make a click state using only CSS?

E.g. darken the background slightly more for 0.1 sec on each click.

Browser compatible solutions preferred but not required.

Comment: please share with what you came up

Comment: I made a quick fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/x50hud0g/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe the `:active` pseudo class is what you are after:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp

A 0.1 sec delay could be achieved using CSS3 transitions, however using jQuery would be simpler and work across more browsers.

Answer (score 2):

**The problem here is the "each click"!**

It would be possible to "delegate" one state.

State one -> not clicked
State two -> clicked (by selector `:active` or `:focus`)

But if you want to have an increment / decrement functionality you must not use plain css.